# Refactoring in symfony 4 HTTP response

Tags: php, try-catch, refactoring, symfony4

I'm sorry for my poor English.

I'm making an API Rest call in Symfony 4. I have the next portion code:

```
public function registerAction() {
    $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = [];
    $message = "";
    try {
        $code = 200;
        $error = false;
        // **here the controller logic**;

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $code = 500;
        $error = true;
        $message = " {$ex->getMessage()}";
    }

    return $this->jsonResponse($code, ($error == true) ? $message :  $user);
```

Is this code is the same for all the controllers, make the logic and return the result or the error?

I want to make a hereditable method to refactor this code, now the unique solution we have is to use the call_user_func_array:

```
public function ejecutarContenido($code,$data){
    $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = [];
    $error = false;
    $message = "";
    $code = 200;
    try {
        $result = call_user_func_array($callSP, array($parametros));;

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $code = 500;
        $error = true;
        $message = " {$ex->getMessage()}";
    }

    return $this->jsonResponse($code, ($error == true) ? $message :  $user);
}
```

But this is not the best way to accomplish this. I want my controller to execute the logic, and if an error occurs, the hereditable method immediately catches the exception and return the status, or if all is okay return the data.

In conclusion, I want my controllers running into a try/catch but not locally.